# How can I render a Google Sheets Cell's value in a Google Doc?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

Currently, it is possible to click a cell in Google Sheets and "get a link", however, when this "link" to the cell is inserted in a Google Doc, it hyperlinks to the Google Docs app, and does not show the cell value.

How can I render a Google Sheet Cell's VALUE in a Google Doc?

[image]

[image]

**EDIT:**
To clarify, let's say I have my favorite number in a cell of a Google Sheet, and I want to have that number referenced in a Google Doc.  I want this to look like the first line of the image below.  The following lines are what I get if I command-C copy the cells in the Sheet, based on the answer from @doubleunary, which is not as ideal but at least it's closer to what I want!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: You are showing two versions of what you _do not want_. It would probably make it easier to understand what you want if you showed an illustration of what you _do want_.

Comment: thanks @doubleunary I made an update to clarify what I want, and also what I am getting so far from your answer.

Comment: Since the paste link feature requires two cells at minimum, you should put the phrase "My Favorite number is:" and the number in adjacent spreadsheet cells, and then copy-paste those two cells as described in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can link a Google Sheets range to a Google Docs paragraph by using simple copy and paste. Just select the range (*note: minimum two cells*), press **Control+C** to copy, then open the text document and press **Control+V** to paste.

You will be asked if you want to paste the table as a link to the spreadsheet or if you want to paste the table unlinked. Choose the first option to make Docs automatically show an **Update** button on top of the table whenever the source data has changed.

Note that the dynamically linked option is not totally automatic as you will still need to click the button to refresh the values.

Answer (score -1):

once you have created the linked range of at least 2 cells, you can edit the range and select a single cell.